# Return value from overloaded method with Sinon

Tags: typescript, sinon

I have the following example class, which has a overloaded method `bar`.

```
class Foo {
  bar(value: string): string;
  bar(value: number): number;
  bar(value: string | number): string | number {
    return value;
  }
}
```

In my tests I am normally creating an instance of foo and stubbing it.

```
const foo = new Foo();

const stub = Sinon.stub(foo, "bar");
```

When I stub the `number` part of the function, everything is still ok.

```
stub.withArgs(1).returns(2);
```

This above code is working without errors.

But this is not my use case. I want to stub the `string` part of my method like the following.

```
stub.withArgs("hello").returns("world");
```

When I do this, my IDE tells me the following:

For `"hello"`:

> Argument of type '"hello"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | SinonMatcher | undefined'.

For `"world"`:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

If I change the order of my overloaded methods, I would be successfully able to stub the `string` method, but not the `number` method. However, I can not change this order.

My question is: How can I stub the `string` part and not the `number` part of my method `bar`?